# How would I go about adding a uiview vertically above a uiview within an inputAccessoryView?

Tags: swift, uiview

I'm trying to add a uiview containing multiple buttons, above my current input accessory view. My current input accessory view is a growing textField (like iOS standard Text Message app).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let textInputBar = ALTextInputBar()

// The magic sauce
// This is how we attach the input bar to the keyboard
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return textInputBar
    }
}

// Another ingredient in the magic sauce
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

[Example of what I'm trying to do, the app (Facebook Messenger) has a growing textfield or textinput, and in this case, an bar of buttons bellow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b93L.jpg)

[My current view, as mentioned earlier.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv1lW.png)

Comment: can you screen shots. for more details.

Comment: Can't u add a view with both TextField and Button view as accessory view- e.g. V:|[BUTTONVIEW][TEXTFIELD]| - . Or use keyboard show/hide Notifications and manually add it on the view. eg. can get keyboard height from notification. Calculate inputAccessoryView height and place teh button view using this height value. Remove it when kb closed

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala I added a photo of what I'm trying to do, and my current app.

Comment: @RJE I've tried the approach of setting the barView's bottom space to be the height of the textField, but since the textField (textInputBar) grows, it doesn't work. Also, I can only add the barView into the textField superview in the willLoadSubviews method, and he barViews bottom space to be 0px above the textField . If I try viewDidLoad, the textInputBar's superview is nil. Adding it in willLoadSubview doesn't increase the barViews vertical location, as the textField bar grows.

Answer (score 0):

> try this code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
var textInputBar:UIView = ALTextInputBar()// if it is a uiview type

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = textInputBar
 }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it did not work. It gave me the error: Cannot assign to property: inputAccessoryView is a get only property.